# Error when compare performance of del for dict and list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm doing programming exercise from Problem solving with algorithms and data structures.The exercise is to compare performance of del operator on lists and dictionaries, here's the code:

```
import timeit, random
from timeit import Timer

for i in range(1000000, 100000000, 1000000):
    x = list(range(i))
    t = Timer("del x[random.randrange(%d)]" %i,\
              "from __main__ import random,x")

    y = {j: None for j in range(i)}
    key = random.choice(list(y.keys()))
    t1 = Timer("del y[%d]" %key,\
               "from __main__ import y")

    time1 = t1.timeit(number=1000)          
    time = t.timeit(number=1000)

    print("%d, %15.5f, %15.5f" % (i, time, time1))
```

Here's the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Problem_Solving\chapter2_del_list_dict.py", line 17, in <module>
    time = t.timeit(number=1000)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

And sometimes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Problem_Solving\chapter2_del_list_dict.py", line 18, in <module>
    time1 = t1.timeit(number=1000)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
KeyError: 280015
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the repeats of the timed snippet are run on the same `x`.  So once an element is deleted, the list is shorter, then after you delete another element, it's even shorter, and so on.  Eventually, it is likely that you will randomly try to delete an index that isn't there any more, because the list has become too short.

Your second example, with the dict, will always fail, because there you're choosing which key to delete outside the entire `timeit` snippet.  So on the first timeit run, it will delete a key, then on the second run it will try to delete the same key again, which will fail because that key isn't there anymore.

Comment: This type of thing is difficult to test in a precise way.  One possibility is to move the list/dict creation into the tested snippet.  This will inflate the tested timings, but you could then do a separate test of just the list/dict creation time and subtract that to get an estimate of the deletion time.